# Assigning a string to a variable of type int

Tags: c

Why is it that I can assign a string to a variable of type int? Eg. the following code compiles correctly:

```
int main(int argv, char** argc){
    int a="Hello World";
    printf(a);
}
```

Also, the program doesn't compile when I assign a string to a variable of a different type, namely double and char.

I suppose that what is actually going on is that the compiler executes `int* a = "Hello World";` and when I write `double a="Hello World";`, it executes that line of code as it is.

Is this correct?

Comment: Take a look at this thread - http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/99454-howto-assign-address-integer-variable.html

Comment: You need to turn on some compiler warnings if you don't get any when you compile that, or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, that assignment is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic (possibly just a warning) from any conforming C implementation.  The C language standard does not define the behavior of the program.

**EDIT :** The constraint is in section 6.5.16.1 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), which describes the allowed operands for a simple assignment.  The older C90 standard has essentially the same rules.  Pre-ANSI C (as described in K&R1, published in 1978) did allow this particular kind of implicit conversion, but it's been invalid since the 1989 version of the language.

What probably happens if it does compile is that

```
int a="Hello World";
```

is treated as it if were

```
int a = (int)"Hello World";
```

The cast takes a pointer value and converts to int.  The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined; if `char*` and `int` are of different sizes, it can lose information.

Some conversions may be done explicitly, for example between different arithmetic types.  This one may not.

Your compiler *should* complain about this.  Crank up the warning levels until it does.  (Tell us what compiler you're using, and we can tell you how to do that.)

**EDIT :**

The `printf` call:

```
printf(a);
```

has undefined behavior in C90, and is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic, in C99, because you're calling a variadic function with no visible prototype.  If you want to call `printf`, you *must* have a

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

(In some circumstances, the compiler won't tell you abut this, but it's still incorrect.)  And given a visible declaration, since `printf`'s first parameter is of type `char*` and you're passing it an `int`.

And if your compiler doesn't complain about

```
double a="Hello World";
```

you should get a better compiler.  That (probably) tries to convert a pointer value to type `double`, which doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Thanks. I should pay more attention to the compiler warnings.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't make sense to convert a pointer value to a type double, but it also doesn't make sense to convert it to a type char. The only warning I get from this code `char a=(char)"Hello World\n"; printf("%p", a);` is that they have different sizes. By the way, the output is `0xffffffb0`.

Comment: Pointer-to-integer conversions generally make *some* sense; they can be useful (if non-portable) as long as the integer type is big enough to hold the converted pointer value without loss of information (such conversions are "intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment").  A pointer-to-char conversion almost certainly loses information.  And printing a char value with `%p` has undefined behavior (to see the *actual* value, cat to int and use `"%d"`).  Pointer-to-floating conversions aren't illegal, but nothing in the standard defines their behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`"Hello World"` is an array of characters ending with `char '\0'`

When you assign its value to an `int a`, you assign the address of the first character in the array to `a`. GCC is trying to be kind with you.

When you print it, then it goes to where `a` points and prints all the characters until it reaches `char '\0'`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't convert `a`; rather, it treats the address of the first character of the array as an integer.  The code 'works' on a 32-bit platform.  It might not work on a 64-bit platform because the `int` is a 32-bit quantity and the pointer a 64-bit quantity.  If any of the high-order 32-bits are set in the address, then the pointer will be truncated and won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Although it works on my system, which is a 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

It will compile because (on a 32-bit system) int, int *, and char * all correspond to 32-bit registers -- but double is 64-bits and char is 8-bits.

Comment: From what I gathered from the previous posts, I don't think that the size of double is the reason why my program didn't compile (Please correct me if I'm wrong). I think the reason was that it doesn't make sense to convert a pointer value to type double or type char. Even if char* and int were of different sizes, the program would still compile. In fact, the following code doesn't give a compiler error: 'char* a = (char)"Hello World";'. It just gives a compiler warning since char* and char are of different sizes.

Comment: **Correction** I meant to write `char a = (char)"Hello World";`

Answer (score 0):

When compiled, I get the following warnings:

```
[11:40pm][wlynch@wlynch /tmp] gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:4: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
foo.c:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
foo.c:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
foo.c:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
foo.c:6: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

As you can see from the warnings, `"Hello World"` is a pointer, and it is being converted to an integer automatically.

The code you've given will not always work correctly though. A pointer is sometimes larger than an int. If it is, you could get a truncated pointer, and then a very odd fault when you attempt to use that value.

Answer (score 0):

It produces a warning on compilers like GCC and clang.

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

The string literal `"Hello World"` is a `const char *`, so you are assigning a pointer to an `int` (i.e. casting the address of the first character in the string as an `int` value). On my compilers, gcc 4.6.2 and clang-mac-lion, assigning the string to `int`, `unsigned long long`, or `char` all produce warnings, not errors.

This is not behavior to rely on, quite frankly. Not to mention, your `printf(a);` is also a dangerous use of `printf`.

Comment: I think the whole code is dangerous. I was just experimenting with different parts of the language.